# Animation like cards app iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, core-animation, flip, cabasicanimation

I am trying to achieve the same effect like in cards app (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWjX_qufmc0) for opening the content inside (Horizontal greeting card opening type animation: https://store.marathonpress.com/image/cache/data/store_381/Previews/Press-Printed-Card-Folded-5x7-H-C-500x500.jpg). I have tried it using `CABasicAnimation` but no access, Can someone help me to achieve the same animation effect.

I am trying like this:

```
- (void)loadInsideMessageView {

    [UIView transitionWithView:backgroundView
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom //any animation
                    animations:^ {
                        insideView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 568, 280);
                        [backgroundView addSubview:insideView];
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For create necessary animation you can use [Core Animation Function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html).

Create new `Single View Application` project and insert the code below in `ViewController.m` for see how it works.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

  //create frame for 2 test views
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 100.0 , 200.0 ,100.0);

  //lower view
  UIView *insideViev = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
  [insideViev setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

  //upper view
  UIView *pageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  [pageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

  [[self view] addSubview:insideViev];
  [[self view] addSubview:pageView];

  //get layer of upper view and set needed property
  CALayer *viewLayer = [pageView layer];
  [viewLayer setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint){0.5 , 0.0}];
  [viewLayer setFrame:frame];

  //create perspective
  CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
  mt.m34 = 1.0/-500.;

  //create rotation
  CATransform3D open = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI_4, 1, 0, 0);

  //create result transform
  CATransform3D openTransform = CATransform3DConcat(open, mt);

  [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^
   {
 //close animation
 [viewLayer setTransform:openTransform];
   } completion:^(BOOL finished)
   {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^
      {
        //close animation
        [viewLayer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
      }];
   }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ruslan, its great. But I am having two issues, (1). I want that the animation should undergo to the top gray navigation bar as it is now appearing on top of it. (2). Also the transformed view has its image appearing on it, can it be simple white? its should not show the shadow of the image, can i change it alpha or some other relevant approach? Please see the screenshot![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ONhWB.png)

Comment: I have managed to do the 1st issue by adding the subview to below the top view [backgroundView insertSubview:selectedTemplateImgView belowSubview:navBar]; but still need help for the 2nd solution.

Comment: All what I can think of 2nd issue - you can add layer (by defult UIView contain 1 layer , but it can contain more then 1 layer)  below layer with image and animate both layers.

Comment: In this tutorial [Create a 3D Page Folding Animation: Page Sketch & Spine Fold Effect](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/create-a-3d-page-folding-animation-page-sketch-spine-fold-effect/) well said about this: _There is a parallel layer hierarchy corresponding to the view hierarchy on screen. This means that if (say) a label is a subview to a button, then the label’s layer is the sublayer to the button’s layer. Strictly speaking, this parallelism holds only as long as we don’t add our own sublayers to the mix._

Comment: Also may help to understand anatomy of layers :[Building a Layer Hierarchy from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/BuildingaLayerHierarchy/BuildingaLayerHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH6-SW18)

Comment: I have tried like this [selectedTemplateImgView.layer addSublayer:selectedTemplateLayer];
    //[selectedTemplateImgView.layer insertSublayer:selectedTemplateLayer atIndex:1]; but no success, The layer is adding but exactly on top of imageView. I think it is removing the imageviews layer before adding it? I want the layer to be added at the back of uiimageview.

Comment: Unfortunately now I can not build the test project to check my idea. But here's what I think: you need to make the correct hierarchy of layers. `Layer` will contain a mirrored image inside of the card, and a `sublayer` - outside normal picture postcards.

Comment: Yes i added the sublayer to the parent layer, it is added and animating properly, But i think it is not in proper hierarchy. I will check it again.

Comment: To include additional information, you can just [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20350606/104223). (This section is only for answers.) If you have a new question, better to open a separate thread.